Elementary proof of no nontrivial rational points on $y^2-y=x^3-x^2$
I've been working through finding elliptic curves with a point of a given order, and I managed to show that finding an elliptic curve with a point of order 11 corresponds to finding a nontrivial rational point on $y^2-y=x^3-x^2$. I know from the LMFDB that there are no nontrivial points, but is there an elementary way of showing this?

"...is there an elementary way of showing this?" Which "this" do you have in mind: that  $y^2-y=x^3-x^2$ has no nontrivial rational points, or that this would be equivalent to finding an elliptic curve with a point of order 11?

I managed to prove the latter, that it is equivalent to finding an elliptic curve with a point of order 11. It's the no nontrivial rational points part that I'm seeking an elementary proof for.

I doubt something “very elementary” is possible. The problem was considered by Beppo Levi at the beginning of the 20th century and he couldn’t solve it. I “know” a modern proof by 5-descent, but this is not elementary. After a brief scan, I can’t locate the original proof in the literature (starting from the Eisenstein ideal and Mazur-Tate papers and backtracking), but this is probably somewhere (https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/plms/s3-33.2.193 is promising but paywalled). Presumably your best chance is to take a deep breath and work out the 2-descent.

This is described in a few different sources as the "Billing-Mahler theorem", referring to "On exceptional points on cubic curves" from 1940 (available without paywall here). I lack the background to assess whether that is an 'elementary' proof.

As far as I know the first time the 5(-isogeny) descent appeared in the literature is in Mazur's Inventiones paper "Rational points of abelian varieties with values in towers of number fields" Corollary 9.10 -- not such an elementary argument (though it can presumably be simplified a lot by removing generality)
